# Java redefine a method dynamically

Tags: java

Is it possible to define a method without extending classes?

```
((JComponent) c).paintComponents(Graphics a) {
    // Paint some one
};
```

Comment: What's your goal? Are you just trying to reduce the number of classes you write? Would using an anonymous class do what you need?

Comment: In Java, all methods have to be defined inside a class.  If you want a method to be available without instantiating a class, use the `static` qualifier.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-extension-methods

Answer (score 3):

No, but if you are just trying to reduce the number of classes you have to define you could use an anonymous class

```
JComponent c = new JComponent() {
    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, but it's too complex so it must be done only if you really need such feature. On the other hand, you may use decorator pattern to add behavior to your objects dynamically.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I wouldn't call this complex and then go suggest bytecode manipulation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I referred to complex for *yes you can (using bytecode manipulation)*. In fact, IMO we don't have enough info in the question to provide a proper answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. That confused me too, did you mean "bytecode manipulation is complex" from the other answer as opposed to anonymous classes from my answer?

Comment: Yes, bytecode manipulation can be too complex to solve this problem, but it's indeed a solution (and a Yes, it's possible rather than a No). This may solve OP's problem but IMO I cannot say what's the specific problem to solve.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Thank you, the penny drops (for me) - when I said "No, but ..." you were rightly saying "Yes you can, if you do ... (complex stuff)".  I am in violent agreement with you. I think the OP is potentially giving us the [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My answer was a guess at the solution to his actual problem and an assumption that he wanted to do some kind of Java equivalent to C# extension methods. I did ask him for more context but we don't have it yet.

Comment: @Luigi isnt bytecode manipulation the solution to all IT problems? For example if you manipulate your hard drive's stored bytecode by installing a new application... : )

Answer (score -1):

No. It's impossible. Java isn't interpreted programming language. It's compiled.For example you can do it in Ruby.

Comment: **Wrong**. You can do it with bytecode manipulation using a library like cglib that let's you write code *on the fly*.

Comment: Yes, but i dont need a manipulation with external libs like Javaassist or other

Comment: @AdrianPreuss it will be great if you give more context to the problem. Basically, a good answer will be: *Yes, you can. Period*.

Comment: Yes, you can. But it'll be a bad designed solution. If you real need use this feature, you should to think about using other programming language.

Comment: @Cortwave using bytecode manipulation is not a bad design solution. It depends on what you need. For example, Spring does this when it needs to creates proxies for your classes to add transaction management features on them, and I don't think they are following bad practices for all these years in the market. We lack proper context, so there is no specific answer for this rather than *yes, it is possible*.